# Эмуляция нажатия клавиши unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как в Unity сделать эмуляцию нажатия клавиши на клавиатуре? Чтобы на него реагировали и внешние программы. 
Мышкой мы можем, например, подвигать так

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]

public static extern int SetCursorPos(int x, int y);

Vector2 mousePos;

mousePos = new Vector2(1,2)
```

А ввести клавишу на клавиатуре?

Comment: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/945299/how-to-trigger-a-button-click-from-script.html   http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/588786/is-it-possible-to-simulate-a-keypressinput-in-code.html  Попробуй гуглить еще и на  английском.

Comment: Может если скажешь зачем это, то тебе посоветует какое нибудь решение. Я не могу представить зачем такое может понадобится...

Comment: @ValeraKvip Использовать Unity вне окна Unity. Чтобы можно было открыть другие программы, найти мышкой на рабочем столе нужный ярлык. Понимаю, обычно Unity для такого не используют, но хотелось бы попробовать все её возможности. По вашим ссылкам есть решение со скачиванием доп.ассетов, встроенного функционала нет такого?

Comment: Это уже работа с ОС. Можно открыть разные окна из ВинФормс. Юнити это игровой все таки движок. В общем можно все, но нужно выйти за пределы юнити.

Comment: @ValeraKvip  подразумеваете что средствами юнити такое не сделать? 
Или из юнити всё таки можно нажать клавишу? Мышкой же можно через работу с user32.dll

Comment: В Unity это задача ничем не отличается. Импортируйте dll. Советую вот эту: https://github.com/michel-pi/InputManager.Net. Подключаете библиотеку и в путь